# WooCoomerce: cannot change menu color on the woocommerce pages only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, menus, headers

I have a problem with the transparent header. While it looks good on the main pages, in the shop, cart, and checkout pages of WooCommerce, the transparent header doesn't work because the menu items are in white color and the background is white as well. However, I added some CSS to change the color of the WooCommerce menu, but it still affects the menu of all the other pages. I also disabled the transparent header in WooCommerce Product Pages option but it doesn't seem to work anyway. Anyone can help me, please? Thanks

[image]
[image]